# I am trying to make a strip of images, they(each image) will give a click effect(kind of) when hovered

Tags: html, css

The hover effect works but only with image encapsulated in the div. I want the entire div to give hover effect.
This is my CSS code:

```
#quickstrip {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
/*background-color: #f4f4f4;*/
background-color: #B4985A;
height: auto;
padding-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.quickstrip_image{
display: block;
float: left;
width: 15% ;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
-ms-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
margin: 10px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px #363024;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.quickstrip_image :hover{
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
position:relative;
top:3px;
margin:0px;
}
```

This is HTML:

```
<div id="quickstrip">

<div class="quickstrip_image"><a href="#" target="_self"><img alt="Compass" height="143" src="http://i.imgur.com/ouT4aeC.png" width="117" /> </a></div>

<div class="quickstrip_image"><a href="#" target="_self"><img alt="Compass" height="143" src="http://i.imgur.com/0edw7a0.png" width="117" /> </a></div>

<div class="quickstrip_image"><a href="/#" target="_self"><img alt="Compass" height="143" src="http://i.imgur.com/4ZNPr6T.png" width="117" /> </a></div>

<div class="quickstrip_image"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="Compass" height="143" src="http://i.imgur.com/n1GR9dp.png" width="117" /> </a></div>

<div class="quickstrip_image"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="Compass" height="143" src="http://i.imgur.com/3e771UM.png" width="117" /> </a></div>

<div class="quickstrip_image"><a href="#" target="_self"><img alt="Compass" height="143" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZRIGbGt.png" width="117" /> </a></div>
</div>
```

I tried adding the span tag with "quickstrip_image" class, thinking it might work, but didn't.
The image moves within the div which is not what I want, I want the entire div to give hover effect.

This is the fiddle for my work: http://jsfiddle.net/veniarya/ys219nsa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.quickstrip_image :hover` to `.quickstrip_image:hover`. That space makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

```
.quickstrip_image:hover{
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #363024;
position:relative;
display: block;
top:3px;
}
```

removed the space right after quickstrip_image

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/veniarya/ys219nsa/